How to include static .dlls in SBOM?
I'm trying to generate an SBOM for a .NET/WPF application.
Using the Microsoft sbom-tool successfully identifies dependencies on NuGet packages, but several of our dependencies are already-compiled .dlls. How do I include these in the SBOM? Is there a different tool that will automatically pick them up? If I were to manually add references to the generated SBOM, what information is needed?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
